# Android SurfaceComposerClient

Tags: android, surface

on Android SurfaceComposerClient or SurfaceControl
how can I set one layer to specific display? such as display_id 1-2?
I have tried setLayerStack doesn't work for me.

Comment: bit more 
I got PhysicalDisplayId for my display
is there any way to set layer to this PhysicalDisplayId?

Comment: Please, try adding further information. See [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)